# Redirecting stdout from two programs

Tags: command-line, io-redirection, stdout

I'm running a memory check tool (prog1) on a C++ code (prog2), both of which give me a huge and detailed output. In order to chase down some bugs I need to save this output to a file.

I tried redirecting the stdout to a file:

```
prog1 prog2 > outfile.txt
```

But that gives me a file containing the output of prog2, while the output of prog1 is still going to the terminal.

Anyone know a way to specify that I want BOTH outputs to go to a file? Like `(prog1 prog2) > outfile.txt`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There’s a good chance that `prog1` is writing its output to standard error. You can redirect both outputs to a single file with

```
prog1 prog2 > outfile.txt 2>&1
```

or you can split the outputs with

```
prog1 prog2 > outfile.txt 2> errors.txt
```

This doesn’t separate the individual *programs*’ output, it separates the output channels. See [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/86440) for details.

If you look at `prog1`’s documentation, you might find an option to tell it to store its output in a named file instead. For example, with `strace`,

```
strace -o strace.txt prog2 > outfile.txt
```

would store `strace`’s output in `strace.txt`, and everything written to standard output in `outfile.txt`.

Comment: `2>&1` has to go *after* `> outfile.txt`. Order of redirections matter.

Comment: Note to future readers: @Barmar is absolutely correct that the relative order of redirections matter with respect to each other. For those less familiar, the order of redirections with respect to program arguments only matters in a few cases. The beginning and end are common locations, but the middle happens sometimes as well (please don't do this). `echo >&2 hello world` is equivalent to `echo hello world >&2`. More info here: https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html